# Image is overlapping text on browser resize

Tags: css, image-resizing, overlap

I've gone through CSS validation (which did find some pesky unclosed tags, sorted now).
I'm trying to align an image to the top right side of my page, with title text on the top left.

I can do this, but when I resize the browser window the image always wants to overlap the title text before either of them resize. If I remove the margins that I've used to place the image then the image sits under the title text (and to the right) instead of just to the right of it, but I feel removing this (while keeping the positioning) might be key. I do need the image to be overlapped by some other elements though.

Here's a snippet of my code for the image:

```
img#site-logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: -12.87em 2em -16em 0px;
}
```

And for the site title:

```
#site-title a {
    font-size: 4.875em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 78px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Site is live here:

http://dominicpalma.com/

Comment: firstly, Labour, BOO!!! :)  so what are you trying to achieve, a responsive website?

Comment: Are you trying to build a responsive layout or it's desktop only? using min-width on #page might be enough but depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: I'd like something responsive, yes - so that it works on various screens.

Answer (score 2):

There are surely several different approaches to solve your problem.
But in my eyes it would be the best solution to set a `min-width` for your `#page` element.

```
#page{
    min-width:900px;
}
```

I have played a little bit around with the width and think a `min-width` of 900 px fits best in your case.

Comment: Thanks - that does stop it overlapping, but then the page won't fit on smaller screens and mobile devices. I'm hoping for a solution that will resize all the page elements dynamically - is this not possible?#

Comment: sure that is possible, but then you have to do more than a quick and easy fix. Then you must restructure your whole page concept and should better know the details about responsive design and coding.

Comment: Since I'm quite early on in my page design, is there anywhere you could point me? Of course, the less restructuring still the better...

Comment: To get a jumpstart into responsive design take a look here: http://www.tutslist.com/responsive-design-tutorials-and-tools/

Comment: I have started with a responsive Wordpress theme (http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/) as a base - is it possible that I have 'broken' its responsiveness?

Comment: Depending on what you have changed, it is surely possible that you have broken the responsive functionality. You really should better start learning about responsive designs before you try to change the templates.

Comment: Agreed. Well, I'll go back to the drawing board and see if there's another way of working this out.